# If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ , is $|f|$ Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ , is $|f|$ Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ ?
(The metric is $\mathbb R$ usual)

The other is question is $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ , can I claim $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ ? (I think the answer can be either yes or no that depend on considerating generalized function or not)

Update: I think I made a mistake on second question that both definitions of Riemann integral and generalized Riemann integral on [a,b] request the f being bounded on [a,b]. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Riemann Integration is only considered for bounded functions

Comment: @MrSelberg: I've calculated the integral of $f(x)=1/\sqrt x$ and the result is 2 when I used ε+ to replace 0. Seems the definition of $f(x)$ at 0 has no effect on the integral?

Comment: Correct, it have not effect.

Comment: @learnmore: so if $f$ ∈ $R[a,b]$, will it imply $f$ ∈ $B[a,b]$?

Comment: @MrSelberg, that function is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$. Do not confuse "improperly Riemann integrable" with "Riemann integrable".

Comment: @SantiagoCanez True. I apologize for the mistake.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez: What's the name of integral of $f(x) = 1/\sqrt x$ on[0,1]?

Comment: It is more general than that. Refer to theorem 6.11 of baby rudin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the reverse triangle inequality we have

$$\begin{align}\sup_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}|f|(x) - \inf_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}|f|(x) \\&=\sup_{x,y \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}| |f(x)|-|f(y)|| \\ &\leqslant \sup_{x,y \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}| f(x)-f(y)| \\ & = \sup_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x) - \inf_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x).\end{align}$$

For a given partition $P = (x_0,x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, the difference of upper and lower sums
is

$$U(P,|f|) - L(P,|f|) = \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sup_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}|f|(x) - \inf_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}|f|(x)\right)(x_j - x_{j-1})\\ \leqslant  \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sup_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x) - \inf_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x)\right)(x_j - x_{j-1})\\= U(P,f) - L(P,f)$$

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P$ such that the difference of upper and lower Darboux sums satisfies

$$U(P, |f|) - L(P, |f|) \leqslant U(P,f)-L(P,f) < \epsilon.$$

Hence, $|f|$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: what is Darboux sum?

Comment: Just the usual upper and lower (Riemann) sums -- technically the name Darboux is applied.  Also if a function is Riemann integrable, then it is bounded.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1177188/148510

Comment: Thanks. I think your proof is correct.

Comment: Yes. f is Riemann integrable necessarily means f is bounded coz bounded f is a part of the definition of Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Frank_W: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the fact that $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if and only if it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere on $[a,b]$.

Let $f(x)$ be Riemann integrable on [a,b]. Then $f$ is bounded and continuous almost everywhere. Define $f_+(x)$ by $f_+(x)=f(x)$ if $f(x)>0$, and $f_+(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $f_+(x)$ will also be bounded and continuous almost everywhere. Thus $f_+(x)$ is Riemann integrable. Similarly, define $f_-(x)$ by $f_-(x)=f(x)$ if $f(x)\leq 0$ and $f_-(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $f_-(x)$ is also Riemann integrable by the same reasoning as above. Riemann integrability of $|f(x)|$ follows since $|f(x)|=f_+(x)-f_-(x)$.

Answer (score -2):

Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary

Let $P=\{a=x_0<x_1<x_2<....<x_n=b\}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ with $||P||<\delta$

let $M_i=\sup _{({x_{i-1},x_i})}f$ and $m_i=\inf _{({x_{i-1},x_i})}f$

let $M_i^{'}=\sup _{({x_{i-1},x_i})}|f|$ and $m_i^{'}=\inf _{({x_{i-1},x_i})}|f|$

Then $\sum_{i=1}^n\{|M_i^{'}-m_i^{'}|\}\Delta x_i\leq \sum_{i=1}^n|M_i-m_i|\Delta x_i<\epsilon$

Comment: Why do you say $|M_i|=\sup_{(x_{i-1},x_i)}|f|$? That's not true in general, if $f$ is positive, this is true... but then we have nothing to prove.

Comment: I think MrSelberg's comment is right. Some bugs need to be fixed.

Comment: I don't know. I do not click downvote. Still thanks, learnmore