# Prove that if $f$ is Riemann integrable, $|f|$ is Riemann integrable, using the pure Riemann-sum definition.

Tags: real-analysis

How would this be proven without using upper and lower sums? The definition basically says that $f$ has integral $I$ iff $|S-I|<\varepsilon$ whenever $S$ is a Riemann sum of width $\delta$.

Comment: I think this answer works if you have already proven that if $f,g$ are Riemann integrable over an interval, then $f+g$ is: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1190406/596135

Comment: @B.Núñez we haven't really proven integrable $\iff$ continuous almost everywhere